# java jax rs access files on server

Tags: tomcat, jax-rs

Running Tomcat 7.0
I have a file in my web-inf folder that is accessible through my browser by:

```
http://localhost:8080/wsdarwin_1.0.0/hello.txt
```

How do I go about accessing this file and its contents in java code ( using relative links, I guess ). I can access it just fine using a buffered reader and accessing its full url as such:

```
URL requestURL = new URL(PATH_PREFIX_TWO+"/request.txt");
            BufferedReader testIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(requestURL.openStream()));
```

But isn't there a way to access it 'locally' ? I'm not using Maven

For example, accessing the file locally permits me to do this:
BufferedReader testIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(PATH_PREFIX+"/request.txt")));
where PATH_PREFIX = "C:/users/username/.../hello.txt";

If I were to change PATH_PREFIX to "/hello.txt", it does not access it ( file not found error )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if your file is deployed in WEB-INF/classes or in a jar in WEB-INF/lib, you can access it via `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name)` where `name` if the full name of your resource (eg: `/pkgA/pkgB/hello.text`).

This is a portable solution, there's no need to specify absolute path in the server's file system.

Comment: what if i have files in WebContent, not in the web-inf folder. what is the 'local'/server path to them ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to access such files, because WEB-INF is not part of the classpath (WEB-INF/classes is, thought). What's wrong with having them in WEB-INF/classes or in a jar of WEB-INF/jar ? You could simply keep the original file in a source folder of your project, or put it in WEB-INF/classes during the build of your war file.

Comment: But then I would have to compile my project; I'd like to be able to put any kind of file there and access it through a local path. I thought everything in WEB-INF is not accessible publicly and only through class calls

Comment: ok, so I don't understand what's the problem with your code: "If I were to change PATH_PREFIX to "/hello.txt", it does not access it ( file not found error )" seems correct (there's no such file), what do you need ? You could have a directory anywhere on your disk that maps to a root path when you need to retrieve some files, then have your application load files from that path..